# I am getting error for following code and warning that The type ClipboardManager is deprecated

Tags: android

```
for (TextView currentText : txts) {
        currentText.setTextSize(heightText);
        currentText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ClipboardManager cm = (ClipboardManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                cm.setText(currentText.getText());
                Toast.makeText(context, "Copied to clipboard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            });
    }
```

I have put above code in my onCreate method, my application need to work on API 8+.
`cm.setText(currentText.getText());` gives me this error
Cannot refer to a non-final variable currentText inside an inner class defined in a different method.
and context cannot be resolved to a variable. What is wrong here? And is it O.K. to use deprecated code in my application because i can't find any other method that would work.

**[EDIT]**
Now my code is like this:

```
for (final TextView currentText : txts) {
        currentText.setTextSize(heightText);
        currentText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ClipboardManager cm = (ClipboardManager)this.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                cm.setText(currentText.getText());
                Toast.makeText(this, "Copied to clipboard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            });
```

And errors are 
The method `makeText(Context, CharSequence, int)` in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments `(new View.OnClickListener(){}, String, int)`
The method `getSystemService(String)` is undefined for the type `new View.OnClickListener(){}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try declaring the variable `final` in the `for` loop:

```
for (final TextView currentText : txts) {
```

As for `context`, you need a context. Try `currentText.getContext()`. Or, since this is apparently in an `Activity`, you can simply use `MyActivityClassName.this` instead of `context`.

EDIT: You're close with your edit. Within the `OnClickListener`, you need to qualify `this` when you want to refer to the activity. If your activity class is named `MyActivity`, code like the following should work:

```
for (final TextView currentText : txts) {
    currentText.setTextSize(heightText);
    currentText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ClipboardManager cm = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            cm.setText(currentText.getText());
            Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Copied to clipboard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Note that I got rid of the `this.` qualifier in the call to `getSystemService()`. The alternative would have been to use `MyActivity.this.getSystemService()`.

Comment: What about context and should i worry about deprecated code?

Comment: @user3422722 - I added info about `context` to my answer. If you set your project level to 8 (which is what you want to target anyway), the deprecated code warning should go away.

Comment: Does not setting target SDK version to 8 make it useless on higher versions? I am getting error again, i am updating my question with correction and new errors tha i am getting.

Comment: @user3422722 - Setting the target SDK version to 8 will still allow it to run on newer versions. It might run in compatibility mode, but it will work just fine. But if I can revise my recommendation, leave the target version alone and set the `android:minSdkVersion` attribute to 8 instead. I edited my answer to address the remaining errors.